# How can I modify sign-in page in Meteor Accounts-Entry package

Tags: html, meteor, accounts

how can I find the html and css files for the Meteor Accounts-Entry, specifically the sign-in page, so I can modify the way it looks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You seem to have edited the question, the answer hence further edited :) You should open the packages folder, goto meteor accounts entry, it should have a client folder there, edit it to reflect changes.

Edit 1: Further reading on topic http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor

You should have either use the accounts ui unstyled package or remove the accounts ui views package. The following code should work,change the design via css ofcourse. I'm using materialize.css out here.

```
<template name="login">
    <div class="container">
            <img class="responsive-img logo" src="/images/logotext.png">
        <form id="login-form">
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="login-email">Email</label>
                <input id="login-email" type="email" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label for="login-password">Password</label>
                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="validate">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="waves-effect wave-light btn light-blue">
                Log in
                <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
            </button>

            <center><p>Don't have an account? <a href="{{ pathFor 'register' }}">Register here</a></p></center>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**login.js**

```
  Template.login.events({
    "submit #login-form": function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        Meteor.loginWithPassword(
            { email: $(e.target).find("#login-email").val() },
            $(e.target).find("#login-password").val(),
            function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    $("#login-password").val("");
                    $("#login-email").select();     
                    throwError("The email or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.");                    
                } else {
                    Router.go("whereever");
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. To confirm, right now I have the joshowens:accounts-entry package installed. So if I follow your steps and the steps on the link, would that automatically override the sign-in page? Or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: That will indeed. Also you can edit the default pages by going to the packages folder too.

Comment: No problemo at all, fellow meteor enthusiast ;)

Comment: Jeremy - Do you know where I can find the html page in the accounts-entry package? I opened the package directly in ~/users/username/.meteor/packages/joshowens_accounts-entry but could not find the html page; i could only find the css pages...

Comment: Dude, it seems they have not kept the sign in pages up for grabs. I'd recommend the second method I wrote about forgoing meteor entry totally and using accounts ui unstyled and creating a form yourself.(that what i do personally) That would be far easier, a few built pages don't seem to worth the extra effort. If you indeed want it, the crude method would be to ofcourse fork the github https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry and change the templates and repackage which I don't recommend. I'll see if I can whip out a better way and try how to work around meteor entry when I go back home.